# Zebra PS20J Google Play "Эта модель устройства не поддерживается в манифесте вашего приложения"

Tags: android, google-play

делаю приложение на Zebra PS20J (это продуктовый сканер с Андроидом 8), залил прогу в альфу, но скачать не могу, мол приложение не доступно для моего устройства, в самой консоли если найти данное устройство то пишет что

```
Эта модель устройства не поддерживается в манифесте вашего приложения, поэтому владельцы таких устройств не могут установить его.
```

Может кто сталкивался, что нужно прописать в манифесте что бы заработало, если напрямую все работает отлично.

```
<uses-library
            android:name="com.symbol.emdk"
            android:required="false"/>
```

Уже есть.

Спасибо.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ua.com.newpikalka">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.symbol.emdk.permission.EMDK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">

        <uses-library
            android:name="com.symbol.emdk"
            android:required="false"/>

        <activity android:name=".activities.PaymentActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".activities.ProductInfoActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.darryncampbell.datawedgekotlin.SCAN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".dws.DWReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: нужен полный merged манифест

Comment: @Style-7 добавил)

Comment: а minSdk какое?

Comment: @Style-7 
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: К сожалению, кроме как последовательно удалять строки (или часть) в манифесте и загружать в альфу, ничего порекомендовать не могу. Я начал бы с того, что удалил бы все uses-permission

Comment: @Style-7, спасибо, так и поступлю!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно официальной документации - https://cdn.barcodesinc.com/themes/barcodesinc/pdf/Zebra/ps20.pdf камера присутствует только в модели plus.
Если в вашей модели нет камеры уберите из манифеста разрешение для неё `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"  />`

Comment: Камера есть, что и странно, я убрал, все заработало, но при этом доступ к камере имеется, и отрабатывает корректно даже без uses-permission))